# Arduino Mega and other modules power consumption

Tags: power, current

I have an Arduino Mega 2560 to which I have connected:

- Arduino GSM Shield 2
- Waveshare 10 DOF IMU sensor
- Waveshare NEO-7M-C (B) GPS module
- HC-05 ZS040 Bluetooth module

I am feeding my Arduino a 12V current via the VIN pin, yet both the GSM shield and the GPS module are misbehaving due to low power working conditions. All the modules work perfectly fine individually, or in any combination that does not have both the GSM and the GPS module, as they consume the most power.

My question is how high a voltage would be necessary in order for all of the modules to function correctly and how this voltage should be connected to the Arduino.